# Using substring with text() to remove html tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using jQueryUI autocomplete to pull results from a SQL database. I use the `substring` method to limit results' descriptions to 350 characters. But it seems that I can't use `.text()` alongside with substring to remove all the html tags from the descriptions. When I type in a search term, the console returns

`TypeError: item.description.text is not a function`

Can someone tell me what should be used to remove html tags from descriptions?

```
$(function() {

  $( "#Search" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "get.php",
        dataType:"json",
        data:{q:request.term},
        success: function( data ) {

          response($.map( data.products, function( item ) { return { 

           label:item.name,
           category:item.category,
           description:item.description.text().substring(0,350).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") 
                                     //.text() doesn't work.
}
```

Assigning the Data:

```
 }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {

   var inner_html = '..........<p>'+ item.description +'...</div></div></a>';
```

Comment: try wrapping it in a jquery object: `$(item.description).text()....`

Comment: @BrianGlaz Try `$('<img src="//" onerror=alert("hacked!") />')`

Comment: Try using `item.description.textContent` instead of `item.description.text()`. If you want to use `.text()`, you have to apply it to a jQuery object.

Comment: @seiseises I just tried it but got this error `TypeError: item.description.textContent is undefined`

Comment: @Oriol How is this relevant? If you are retrieving options for an autocomplete, I wouldn't think those options would be populated with user input.

Comment: @BrianGlaz I just wanted to point that your code is vulnerable. Then, it should only be used if the source is trusted (which may be the case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `.text()` is a method of jQuery objects (which contain nodes), and `.textContent` is a property of nodes. Instead, it seems that `item.description` is a string.

Then, you could create a DOM element with the string as its html, and then use `.textContent` or `.text()`. But that is a vulnerable practice:

```
$('<img src="//" onerror=alert("hacked!") />');
```

The safe way is:

```
function stripHTML(html) {
      var sandbox = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument().body;
      sandbox.innerHTML = html;
      return sandbox.textContent;
}
/* ... */
       description: stripHTML(item.description).substring(0,350);
/* ... */
```

Note `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument` doesn't work on old browsers.

Comment: Can you please tell me where this should be placed? It gives me error in `response...{ return {` and no effect at all in  renderItem function.

Comment: Got it! I placed the function in `success: function( data ) {` and it works.